# Cannot execute the sshpass command after the the first sshpass is excuted

Tags: bash, ssh, sshpass

I am trying ssh to each host to run some command, after it is done. The second and the third sshpass command needs to be ran. However, it only run the first command, and then it stops at the second and the third sshpass command. Here is my sample script. 
I call it is sshHostName.sh script, and the script contains

```
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'myPassword' ssh root@hostName1 "echo 'hello1'"
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'myPassword' ssh root@hostName2 "echo 'hello2'"
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'myPassword' ssh root@hostName3 "echo 'hello3'"
```

For this example, I only see hello1 after I run ./sshHostName.sh

How to run the next (sshpass) command once the previous one completed?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to manually ssh three times, and see what happens. This is unlikely to be a problem with sshpass. Either way, not enough information to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I need to put this option there: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no

```
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'myPassword' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=noroot@hostName1 "echo 'hello1'"
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'myPassword' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=noroot@hostName2 "echo 'hello2'"
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'myPassword' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=noroot@hostName3 "echo 'hello3'"
```

So it is working!

Answer (score 0):

Works Great!!! A minor Modification use gap between no and root as

```
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'myPassword' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@hostName1 "echo 'hello1'"
```